# Disjoint Union Topology universal property as instance of final topology's universal property

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, universal-property

I'm studying the final topology on a set $X$ induced by a family $\{f_\alpha:X_\alpha\rightarrow X\mid \alpha\in A\}$ and know of its universal property, namely that given a function $g:X\rightarrow Z$, $g$ is continuous iff $g\circ f_\alpha$ is continuous for all $\alpha\in A$.  Showing this is not difficult, but it is not constructive.

What bothers me about this is that my usual understanding of universal properties is that they refer to initial or terminal properties and morphisms; typically, they involve the existence of a unique morphism, as the definitions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) suggest.  As this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138360/universal-property-of-initial-topology?rq=1) points out, we may use the category of cones along with the forgetful functor from $\mathbf{Top}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$ to show that the above universal property is indeed as the above definitions give.  To be honest, I don't know enough category theory to completely understand the process, which may be where my issue lies.

The question I have is then:

How (or if) the universal property of the disjoint union topology can be realized as a special case of the final topology's universal property, since the disjoint union topology is the final topology induced by the canonical injections of $X_\alpha$ into $X=\amalg_{\alpha\in A}{X_\alpha}$, which is constructive in nature, i.e. that it guarantees the existence of a unique morphism such that a certain diagram commutes.

Comment: Note that first and foremost the disjoint union is the coproduct in $\mathbf{Top}$

Comment: @Stefan The universal property of the coproduct indeed coincides with the universal property given above.  I was hoping that this could be put in terms of the universal property of the final topology as well (and similarly, the product topology as an instance of the initial topology).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. Do you understand the concept of a universal arrow and what a cone is? Then you might have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144689/categorical-construction-of-quotient-topology/144694#144694 where I describe categorically the concept of initial topology, so you have to dualize that text. The idea is that for any cone in **Set** there is a cone in **Top** such that the identity from the Set-cone to the underlying set of the Top-cone is a universal arrow. If the cone in Set is such that all maps are injective and the images are disjoint ...

Comment: ... then it is easy to see that **any** cone in **Top** over the discrete diagram factors through that universal cone equipped with the final topology. And if the images are not only disjoint but even partition the set, then this map is unique.

Comment: Only in a naive sense; as I state in my question, this seems to be where my issues lie.  I'll try and understand the construction to get an idea how they are connected.